# How to write a update SQL using a select SQL

Tags: sql, select, sql-update

I want to write a update SQL statement, but one conidtion of this statement is the result from a select SQL statement, and I also want to return the result of the select SQL statement.

Like this: `update ... set ... where id = (select id from ...)`

I want to return the value of id back.

Does anybody know how should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably you should create a procedure in your RDBMS and call that from java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that's possible in one statement.  Update then query (select) the new value, or query the value first, and then submit an update.

Alternative would be a stored procedure on the database, which executes the multiple queries and returns the result for you.

Comment: Yes, I would follow stored procedure approach.

Comment: A word of warning with store procedures:  Unless you're using them already, they will take you down a route which becomes database specific.  If you want to remain DB agnostic, I'd tend to stay with multiple simple sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in all Java database frameworks that I know. Probably you need to separate your query and update in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem in using a subselect in a WHERE clause of an update statement.

For the second request, getting back the value of id, I know this is possible in DB2, and maybe others implement that syntax too:

```
SELECT id FROM FINAL TABLE (
  update ... set ... where id = (select id from ...)
)
```

This works also for INSERT and DELETE statements. (See the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000875.htm).)

Answer (score 0):

Update statements won't return the updated datasets. The select in that case would be a subselect that isn't directly accessible.

You'd thus have to use at least two queries:

1. select the ids you want
2. call the update query passing the previously selected ids as a parameter